# How to have only redoc url in drf-spectacular

Tags: django

I'm using drf-spectacular for my django project:
https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular

On urls.py I have this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # YOUR PATTERNS
    path('api/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='schema'),
    # Optional UI:
    path('api/schema/swagger-ui/', SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='schema'), name='swagger-ui'),
    path('api/schema/redoc/', SpectacularRedocView.as_view(url_name='schema'), name='redoc'),
]
```

I just want to have 'api/schema/redoc/' so I removed the other two URLs.
After removing 'api/schema/' I get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'schema' not found. 'schema' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

How can I remove that URL like this but resolve the error:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/schema/redoc/', SpectacularRedocView.as_view(url_name='schema'), name='redoc'),
]
```

Comment: `../redoc/` is just the frontend, the actual schema data still needs to be served by `/schema/`.

Comment: I know by there should be another way to don't use the schema url

Comment: The main idea is to use the schema file as is directly to generate some client code from it, for example. The schema file is the main thing here. The redoc or swagger UIs are merely niceties on top. If you want to change this, you'll need to rewrite the implementation to serve the redoc frontend with schema baked in somehow. That's just not what the current implementation does nor attempts to do.

Comment: From what I understand, you mean there is no way to remove the schema URL. Not sure how to do that on drf-spectacular but I know YASG allows you to use only redoc like this without any problem:


re_path(r'^doc/$', schema_view.with_ui('redoc', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-doc'),

Maybe there is a way  to do that on spectacular too

Answer (score 0):

This works for my site:

```
path(
        "docs/",
        SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(
            template_name="swagger-ui.html", url_name="schema"
        ),
        name="swagger-ui",
    ),
    path('docs/redoc/', SpectacularRedocView.as_view(url_name='schema'), name='redoc')
```

,